# javascript null type cannot compare

Tags: javascript

Cannot compare returned json variable type with null. My code:

```
var produkt = eval('(' + html + ')');

console.info(produkt); // I can see the null type: produkt.c_id

if (typeof produkt.c_id !== "undefined" && produkt.c_id) //also null type can't compare
    produkt.c_id.split(',').forEach(function(entry) {
       //...
```

Comment: you never compare if produkt.c_id == NULL (&& produkt.c_id means or checks if produkt.c_id is true. so you are checking if it is undefined or true but not if it is null

Comment: Check that whether produkt is null or not before checking for c_id

Comment: v31: produkt is not null- console.info(produkt) said me that...

caramba: I don't understand... You mean? :
`if ( typeof produkt.c_id != null){`

Comment: just: 
`if (produkt.c_id != null)//without typeof... `
is solution. thanks

Comment: @Jerry1 `undefined` and `null` are two distinct concepts in javascript, unlike many other languages that you may be familiar with. You probably should find and read a short explanation of that on the web.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enought:

```
if (produkt.c_id != null)
    produkt.c_id.split(',').forEach(function(entry) {
        //...
```

This covers both `null` and `undefined`